# FocusChangeListener not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

I have six imageViews in my gridview. I am trying to get the focus changed events for thes imageviews using the following code; but this does not work when I change the focus. Can someone please let me know why and the solution for the same. Any help is much appreciated

```
gridView.setOnFocusChangeListener(new AdapterView.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        //@Override
        public void onFocusChange(View arg0, boolean arg1) {
            Log.d("MyTestActivity", "View:" + arg0.getId() + " boolean = " + arg1);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code only works when focus cnahge on the whole gridview - if you want to listen for the focus on each imageView - you have to set listeners on each of it.
But i think you maybe want something like onItem...Listener ? What goals are you want to achieve ?

Comment: I am changing the focus of these imageviews inside the gridview through voice commands "Up", "Down", "Right", "Left" using dpad keyevents . I can see the highlight getting transferred from one imageview to the other when these commands get executed. Now, I need to listen to the focus change

Comment: try use gridView.setOnItemSelectedListener and gridView.setSelection instead of setFocus for this purposes - it works with dpad. If it will not work or you want only to use Focus then you have to put onFocusChangeListeners on each of your imageView.